# Setting Button's Size in TinyMCE 4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm new with TinyMCE and trying to set the size of some of the buttons in the editor to `small` and some others' to `medium`, in TinyMCE 4.

I know about this property `toolbar_items_size` but this sets all the button's size `small` or `medium`. Instead, I'm trying to set the `size` property of the buttons in `editor.buttons[]` manually after the buttons get registered with the editor but before the theme gets initialized since the theme uses `Factory.create()` to create buttons & that sets class `btn-<size>` to the button, which sets its size.

I've looked into TinyMCE's code too but have not able to figure out a way to do so. Also, I've observed that all the `editor`'s events get fired after the theme gets initialized, like `BeforeSetContent`,..etc.

I'm using `modern` theme.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE simply does not support what you are trying to do - the buttons on the toolbar(s) are a uniform size.  You can pick that uniform size (as you reference) but you can't mix buttons of different sizes on the toolbar.

Comment: Is there any way to change the pixel-by-pixel size of the buttons (for all from one place), like changing 20x20 to 16x16, by css or something else, since setting the `toolbar_items_size` to `small` makes the buttons from `table` plugin almost disappear (shows square in every button instead of the icon) ?

Comment: I don't get that behavior.  Please see this TinyMCE Fiddle:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Rxgaab  Guessing you have some CSS that is conflicting with TinyMCE.

Comment: See this fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Sxgaab, I've only added `table` plugin & a few of its toolbar buttons to the default fiddle, and you can see that it's `small` buttons don't work out correctly, that's what I meant.

Comment: I see what you mean - I would open an issue on the GitHub Issue tracker for that https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues